# Using Rapns to send notifications and I am getting an SSL error on Ubuntu and Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, openssl, apple-push-notifications

I am using https://github.com/ileitch/rapns and it's working great with an Android app, but I'm getting SSL certificate errors when I create a iOS app within it. I've followed the guide in the wiki there, but I'm certainly not an expert with SSL and/or APN servers and certificates. The error is

```
[2013-03-12 12:48:13] [ERROR] [ios_app] Exception raised during startup. Notifications will not be delivered for this app.
[2013-03-12 12:48:13] [ERROR] OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/apns/connection.rb:109:in `connect'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/apns/connection.rb:109:in `connect_socket'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/apns/connection.rb:26:in `connect'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/apns/delivery_handler.rb:8:in `initialize'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/apns/app_runner.rb:31:in `new'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/apns/app_runner.rb:31:in `new_delivery_handler'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:130:in `start_handler'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:70:in `block in start'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:70:in `times'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:70:in `start'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:31:in `sync_app'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:20:in `block in sync'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:20:in `each'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:20:in `sync'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/lib/rapns/daemon.rb:51:in `start'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.1.0/bin/rapns:36:in `<top (required)>'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rapns:23:in `load'
/var/deploy/platter_dev/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rapns:23:in `<main>'
```

I have installed the 'certified' gem and also added the fix_ssl initialiser that are usually recommended for these issues, and OpenSSL is at < version 1 on both my local Mac and Ubuntu staging server.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm seeing the same, have generated the PEM about 3 times now :S Works great on local dev machine but not on Heroku :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an AppID: Sign in to the iOS Developer Center at: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/. Click on the iOS Provisioning Portal and configure your new application to use push notifications.

You can follow the first steps listed here: http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/iphone-configuration-guide/